# In the real line, how many convex subsets are there up to homeomorphism?

Tags: general-topology

I think the answer is 3. The convex sets are intervals, of course, and may be of any type; any two intervals that look alike are homeomorphic. So we add $(a,b)$ and $[a,b]$ to our count. Since intervals like $(c,d]$ are not homeomorphic to either of the previous two intervals, it is a third type. Finally, $(c,d]$ is homeomorphic to $[a,b)$, so we do not add $[a,b)$.

Am I correct?

Comment: Convexity implies connectivity. What are the connected subsets of the real line?

Comment: @R.Chinnapparaj Yes, that's right, although you need to consider a couple more cases: what about intervals like $(-\infty, 18)$? (Your count is right, these don't add anything, but you need to say why.)

Comment: @R.Chinnapparaj: I advise you to add your own comments in the body of the question. This is the first time for me that I see a question without body. I fear that it will get closed pretty soon.

Comment: @NoahSchweber.   I think the two intervals  (−∞,a) and (b,c) are homeomorphic. but i'm unable to provide such a map. How to find?........

Comment: @R.Chinnapparaj You are right, they are! A good way to get started on finding a homeomorphism is to consider the function $f(x)={1\over x}$. What does $f$ to do $(-\infty, -1)$? Do you see how to generalize this? (Another good example to keep in mind is $\arctan$.)

Comment: (@R.Chinnapparaj By the way, you should put the info in your comments into the question itself; then it will be clear to potential answerers exactly what you've tried, and I think the question will be better received.)

Comment: You're close, but you forgot $\{a\}$ and $\varnothing$. These are also convex.